# Create-react-app with express backend works locally but routing incorrect when deployed to heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, spotify, create-react-app

I followed this article on how to create an app using create-react-app with an express backend and the spotify api, and have been trying to deploy it to heroku ever since:
https://medium.com/@jonnykalambay/now-playing-using-spotifys-awesome-api-with-react-7db8173a7b13

Everything seems to be working fine locally, the authorization flows well and once it's completed, express serves a static index.html containing a div with a 'root' id on the client side, and index.js renders the react 'App' component within it.

However, when the app is deployed to heroku, the server-side process still works, authorization and redirect succeed, but the index.html express serves is the upper, server-side one (in the project's root 'public' directory), where no react script is running.
Even when trying to 'force' the script to run by adding react, babel, the index.js script and a 'root' div to this index.html, nothing seems to work.

The Github repo can be found @ https://github.com/Johnnybar/spot.stats and the app can be found @ https://spot-stats.herokuapp.com/

Feels like there is something simple I'm missing here, but after trying to hack my way to deployment for a while now, I'd really appreciate any tips, thanks!

**app.js (app-root/, the authorization flow, succeeds both in heroku and locally)**

```
/**
 * https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization_code_flow
 */

var express = require('express'); // Express web server framework
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library
var querystring = require('querystring');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
let secrets;
let client_id;
let client_secret;
let redirect_uri;
let client_url;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV != 'production') {
    secrets = require('./secrets.json');
    client_id = secrets.client_id;
    client_secret = secrets.client_secret;
    redirect_uri = secrets.redirect_uri;
    client_url = 'http://localhost:3000/#';
}
else{
    client_id =   process.env.CLIENT_ID;
    client_secret =  process.env.CLIENT_SECRET;
    redirect_uri = process.env.REDIRECT_URI; 
    client_url = 'https://spot-stats.herokuapp.com/#';
}
/**
 * Generates a random string containing numbers and letters
 * @param  {number} length The length of the string
 * @return {string} The generated string
 */
var generateRandomString = function(length) {
    var text = '';
    var possible = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
};

var stateKey = 'spotify_auth_state';

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
    .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

    var state = generateRandomString(16);      
    res.cookie(stateKey, state);

    // application requests authorization
    var scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state user-top-read';
    res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
        response_type: 'code',
        client_id: client_id,
        scope: scope,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {

    // application requests refresh and access tokens
    // after checking the state parameter
    var code = req.query.code || null;
    var state = req.query.state || null;
    var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;
    // console.log('here storedstate: ', storedState);

    if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
        res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
          error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
    } else {
        res.clearCookie(stateKey);
        var authOptions = {
            url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
            form: {
                code: code,
                redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            },
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
            },
            json: true
        };

        request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

                var access_token = body.access_token,
                    refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

                var options = {
                    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
                    json: true
                };

                // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
                request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
                    console.log(body);
                });

                // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
                res.redirect(client_url +
          querystring.stringify({
              access_token: access_token,
              refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
            } else {
                res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
              error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
            }
        });
    }
});

app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) {

    // requesting access token from refresh token
    var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
    var authOptions = {
        url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
        headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
        form: {
            grant_type: 'refresh_token',
            refresh_token: refresh_token
        },
        json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            var access_token = body.access_token;
            res.send({
                'access_token': access_token
            });
        }
    });
});

console.log('Listening on 5000');
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

**index.html (app-root/public, displayed on heroku after successful auth - this is not the desired index.html)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Authorization Code flow with Spotify</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      #login, #loggedin {
        display: none;
      }
      .text-overflow {
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        width: 500px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="login">

        <a href="/login" class="btn btn-primary">Log in with Spotify</a>
      </div>
      <div id="loggedin">
        <div id="user-profile">
        </div>
        <div id="oauth">
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="obtain-new-token">Obtain new token using the refresh token</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script id="user-profile-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h1>Logged in as {{display_name}}</h1>
      <div class="media">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <img class="media-object" width="150" src="{{images.0.url}}" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
          <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Display name</dt><dd class="clearfix">{{display_name}}</dd>
            <dt>Id</dt><dd>{{id}}</dd>
            <dt>Email</dt><dd>{{email}}</dd>
            <dt>Spotify URI</dt><dd><a href="{{external_urls.spotify}}">{{external_urls.spotify}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Link</dt><dd><a href="{{href}}">{{href}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Profile Image</dt><dd class="clearfix"><a href="{{images.0.url}}">{{images.0.url}}</a></dd>
            <dt>Country</dt><dd>{{country}}</dd>
          </dl>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>

    <script id="oauth-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <h2>oAuth info</h2>
      <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Access token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{access_token}}</dd>
        <dt>Refresh token</dt><dd class="text-overflow">{{refresh_token}}</dd>
      </dl>
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function() {

        /**
         * Obtains parameters from the hash of the URL
         * @return Object
         */
        function getHashParams() {
          var hashParams = {};
          var e, r = /([^&;=]+)=?([^&;]*)/g,
              q = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          while ( e = r.exec(q)) {
             hashParams[e[1]] = decodeURIComponent(e[2]);
          }
          return hashParams;
        }

        var userProfileSource = document.getElementById('user-profile-template').innerHTML,
            userProfileTemplate = Handlebars.compile(userProfileSource),
            userProfilePlaceholder = document.getElementById('user-profile');

        var oauthSource = document.getElementById('oauth-template').innerHTML,
            oauthTemplate = Handlebars.compile(oauthSource),
            oauthPlaceholder = document.getElementById('oauth');

        var params = getHashParams();

        var access_token = params.access_token,
            refresh_token = params.refresh_token,
            error = params.error;

        if (error) {
          alert('There was an error during the authentication');
        } else {
          if (access_token) {
            // render oauth info
            oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
              access_token: access_token,
              refresh_token: refresh_token
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
                headers: {
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                },
                success: function(response) {
                  userProfilePlaceholder.innerHTML = userProfileTemplate(response);

                  $('#login').hide();
                  $('#loggedin').show();
                }
            });
          } else {
              // render initial screen
              $('#login').show();
              $('#loggedin').hide();
          }

          document.getElementById('obtain-new-token').addEventListener('click', function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: '/refresh_token',
              data: {
                'refresh_token': refresh_token
              }
            }).done(function(data) {
              access_token = data.access_token;
              oauthPlaceholder.innerHTML = oauthTemplate({
                access_token: access_token,
                refresh_token: refresh_token
              });
            });
          }, false);
        }
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.html (app-root/client/public, works locally after auth and renders App component in app/client/src. This is the desired index.html)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>Spotify app</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js (app-root/client/src)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**package.json scripts (app-root/)**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"cd client && npm start\" \"node app.js\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
    "push": "concurrently \"git push heroku master\" \"git push origin master\"",
    "app": "concurrently \"cd client && npm start\" \"node app.js\""
  },
```

**package.json scripts (app-root/client)**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a bundler like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) or [browserify](http://browserify.org/) so that everything in react gets bundled into one js file. This js file will be served by node and you can access it in the html for when you deploy to heroku. I've used them for the same purpose and it works.

If you use webpack, you have to add this to your `scripts` in package.json:

```
"postinstall": "webpack -p",
```

Also, I seem to have a different configuration for the `procfile`, which you can also try:

```
web: node app.js
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but as the react side of the app was created with create-react-app (which keeps most config hidden), it won't be very simple to configure it to work with webpack and an express backend. Locally though, it works

Answer (score 0):

So to answer my own question - it seems like the main issue was with messy configuration and bad routing.
I followed this simple tutorial on deploying a create-react-app with Express backend to heroku and imported my own code, and the app started running fine in a few minutes-
https://dev.to/nburgess/creating-a-react-app-with-react-router-and-an-express-backend-33l3